# Email a .txt file located in application storage directory Air iOS AS3

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, email-attachments, email

I would like to find out, how can I email a .txt file that is located in the application storage directory.

Thanks
Jared

Comment: Have you tried something? I mean a code if any?

Answer (score 0):

Use `applicationStorageDirectory` and `navigateToURL` with `mailto` like so,

(Note: I am not going in depth with reading text file. I can help though if you need help. Putting it only to give some idea here.)

```
//Find the target file
var fileToFind:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("filename.txt");

//Extract content from file
var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
fileStream.openAsync(fileToFind, FileMode.READ);

//fileStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, showContent);
//fileStream.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, alertError);

//To mail 
navigateToURL(newURLRequest("mailto:someEmail@gmail.com"+"?subject=Subject"+"&body="+ textfileContents + "));
```

--

If you want to send attachment or HTML formatted email, see this link,

[SMTPMailer](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=27.)
.

Best luck.

Comment: Thanks so much for the speedy response! ^_^ I'm wanting to email the .txt as an attachment as the contents can be quite lengthy.

Comment: See the bottom link in the answer. It is about 'SMTPMailer'.